# What is meant by "quinoid character"?

Tags: organic-chemistry

While reading about push-pull systems in papers, I came across the term quinoid character. I looked for it in google here is what I've found:

> In polyphenylene the ground state is a whole lot of aromatic rings joined together - very stable. Note that the bond joining the phenyls is a single bond. A quinoid state is one where the double bonds have shifted so that there is a double bond where that above single used to be. This is a high energy state.

I still don't get it and what is the purpose of a high quinoid character?

Comment: Is what you found a quote or your summary of what you have understood so far? Can you provide a reference to any of these papers or the page that this quote came from (if not from you). Also, while the question is on topic here, it may be a better fit for Chemistry SE, unless you are particularly interested in the modeling implications quinoid character.

Comment: Quinoid means relating to or derived from quniones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinone This is almost certainly talking about resonance structures, it would very much help if you can give a/the specific example you are looking at. And I agree, chemistry is probably a better place for this

Comment: thank you @IanBush     so it's a measure of the resonance ?

Comment: A measure its probably taking it too far, but without examples I think it impossible to say more